# What is the tense of "it's supposed to be"?

Tags: tense, contractions

For example,

> I just cleaned the desk an hour ago and it is dirty now. It is not what it's supposed to be.

What is the tense of "it's"? Should it be interpreted as "is" or "was"?

Answer (score 3):

*It was* can not be contracted to *It's*. The *'s* can only be *is* or *has*. Since in this case the auxiliary verb is *to be*, the non-contracted version of your sentence would be:

> It is not what it **is** supposed to be.

The past version is also a correct sentence, but cannot be contracted:

> It **was** supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the present tense. Here's why:

> **It is** supposed to be

The idiom "supposed to be" can also be used in the past tense:

> **It was** supposed to be

But it cannot be used in the future tense.